# Auto Start Firefox and Launch a URL by Default in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, autostart

I want to Autolaunch firefox and load some default URL when my system is Logged IN or rebooted. The option should be in Lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/146457/how-do-i-add-startup-applications-in-lubuntu-lxde - use `firefox <url>` in `Exec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use Upstart:

Create a file `$HOME/.config/upstart/firefox-with-url.conf`

Content:

```
start on desktop-start
stop on desktop-end

exec firefox <url>
```

More info:

http://ifdeflinux.blogspot.de/2013/04/upstart-user-sessions-in-ubuntu-raring.html

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

Comment: It work's fine...

Comment: This will work for GNOME not LXDE.

Answer (score 3):

Goto Menu > Preferences > Default Applications for LXSession > Autostart

There under Manual autostarted applications type "firefox" and click on "add".

E.g.;

[image: Add]

Then, close the window.

Next, open firefox and click on the menu button.

[image: Menu]

Goto Preferences > General (tab)

Enter the desired website you want to visit on Firefox startup.

[image: Website]

Finally, close and restart your PC.

You will be able to autolaunch Firefox and load your entered URL when your system is logged IN or rebooted.

Hope! this helped you. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

People with LXDE in Ubuntu should add:

```
~/.config/autostart/my-new-app-autostart.desktop
```

With similar content to:

```
[Desktop Entry] 

Type=Application

Exec=google-chrome-stable www.google.com.uk
```

It works, I tested it, found it in [lxde.org](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04  in Startup Application in command click on browse and reach this path and save it.

/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh